# Does gunicorn + gevent monkey patch threadlocals to be greenlet-locals automatically?

Tags: python, django, gevent, gunicorn, greenlets

When running gunicorn in gevent mode, are the [monkey patches (particularly those for threadlocals) described here](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.monkey.html), which make threadlocals greenlet-locals, already applied automatically?

(I am running django and currently use threadlocals for a bit of fast-caching of large query results -- I understand gevent/greenlet uses an alternative model to traditional threading, thus my concern).

Comment: Same concern here. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that I have no things to worry about:

https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py#L51